# SQL query to extract the most recent part and anything that is 30 days older than that date.

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and I need to write a query that selects data for a specific part. However, It should select only the part that is the most recent(given by date) and anything that is only 30 days prior to it. Please consider the table below:

```
PartID | Part_NAME | DATE
-----------------------------
  1        AAA     6/16/2015
  2        BBB     6/15/2015
  3        AAA     6/11/2015
  4        AAA     1/1/2008
```

I need a query that gives me:

```
PartID | Part_NAME | DATE
-----------------------------
  1        AAA     6/16/2015
  3        AAA     6/11/2015
```

I have tried:

```
select * from ( select * from sales_table where Part_NAME = 'AAA') where DATE BETWEEN (max(DATE) and  (max(DATE)-30))
```

I have read some articles saying that I cannot use `WHERE` and functions like `max()` together and advised me to use `group by` or `having` but it didn't work for me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want data from the last 30 days of the current day, you can do :

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales_table 
WHERE 
    [DATE] >=  DATEADD(DAY, -30,GETDATE())
AND [DATE] <=  GETDATE()
AND  Part_NAME = 'AAA'
```

IF you want data from the last 30 days from the last date of sale of each `Part_NAME` (this will take the max recorded date of sale for each `Part_NAME` and get the last 30 days records of each one of them.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT *, 
    MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY Part_NAME ORDER BY PartID) AS RecentDate 
FROM sales_table 
) D
WHERE 
    [DATE] >=  DATEADD(DAY, -30, RecentDate)
AND [DATE] <=  RecentDate
AND  Part_NAME = 'AAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish by using datediff and getdate() and a subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,DATEDIFF(DD,[DATE],GETDATE()) AS DAYSBETWEEN FROM sales_table 
    ) AS X
    WHERE DAYSBETWEEN <= 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from the last 30 days, it would be:

```
select st.*
from sales_table st join
     (select top (1) st2.*
      from sales_table st2
      order by st2.date desc
     ) st2
     on st2.part_name = st.part_name and
        st.date >= dateadd(day, -30, cast(getdate() as date));
```